# Process.Start with different credentials with UAC on

Tags: c#, .net, windows-vista, uac

I am trying to start another process with Process.Start running under different credentials with the UAC turned on.  I get the following error:

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception:
>   Logon failure: user account
>   restriction. Possible reasons are
>   blank passwords not allowed, logon
>   hour restrictions, or a policy
>   restriction has been enforced    at
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo
>   startInfo)    at
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
>   at
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo
>   startInfo)

If I turn off UAC, it works fine.  If I start the process without specifying username and password, it works fine.  Below is a copy of the code:

```
            ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            processInfo.Verb = "runas";
            processInfo.FileName = command;
            processInfo.Arguments = parameters;
            processInfo.UserName = txtUserName.Text;
            processInfo.Password = password;
            processInfo.Domain = "myDomain";
            processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            processInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;

            Process.Start(processInfo);
```

I believe this has something to do with the desktop session, but am not sure why it works when UAC is off.

Any ideas on how to get this to work without turning off UAC, modifying the registry, or changing local/group policies would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks

**EDIT**

The Process that has the code above is started as an admin:

```
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         //make sure we are running with admin privileges
         if (VerifyIsAdmin())
         {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new MyApp(args));
         }
      }

      private static bool VerifyIsAdmin()
      {
         WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent());
         bool isAdmin = principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
         if (!isAdmin)
         {
            ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            processInfo.Verb = "runas";
            processInfo.FileName = Application.ExecutablePath;
            Process.Start(processInfo);
         }
         return isAdmin;
      }
```

**EDIT**

Tried [CreateProcessWithLogonW](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.csharp/msg/3e2a3345bdd184d6?pli=1) ... Had same problem.

After further searching, looks like it is a problem with the Group Policy requiring smart card logon (scforceoption).  That being said, I still don't understand why it works when UAC is off.  It should still require smart card on logon.

It doesn't look like I am going to be able to get around this.  Any insight/advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to do following things:
1. Get who is logged in and in this user has an active desktop
2. Get process' handle started by this user
3. "Steal" credentials from this process
4. Start process with those credentials

Following code should do the trick:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Security;
using System.Management;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Win32
{
    public class Win32API
    {
        #region WMI Constants

        private const String cstrScope = "root\\CIMV2";
        private const String cstrLoggenInUser = "SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem";

        #endregion

        #region Win32 API routines

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
        {
            public Int32 Length;
            public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
            public Boolean bInheritHandle;
        }

        enum TOKEN_TYPE
        {
            TokenPrimary = 1,
            TokenImpersonation = 2
        }

        enum TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS
        {
            TokenUser = 1,
            TokenGroups,
            TokenPrivileges,
            TokenOwner,
            TokenPrimaryGroup,
            TokenDefaultDacl,
            TokenSource,
            TokenType,
            TokenImpersonationLevel,
            TokenStatistics,
            TokenRestrictedSids,
            TokenSessionId,
            TokenGroupsAndPrivileges,
            TokenSessionReference,
            TokenSandBoxInert,
            TokenAuditPolicy,
            TokenOrigin,
            MaxTokenInfoClass  // MaxTokenInfoClass should always be the last enum
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct STARTUPINFO
        {
            public Int32 cb;
            public String lpReserved;
            public String lpDesktop;
            public String lpTitle;
            public UInt32 dwX;
            public UInt32 dwY;
            public UInt32 dwXSize;
            public UInt32 dwYSize;
            public UInt32 dwXCountChars;
            public UInt32 dwYCountChars;
            public UInt32 dwFillAttribute;
            public UInt32 dwFlags;
            public short wShowWindow;
            public short cbReserved2;
            public IntPtr lpReserved2;
            public IntPtr hStdInput;
            public IntPtr hStdOutput;
            public IntPtr hStdError;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
        {
            public IntPtr hProcess;
            public IntPtr hThread;
            public UInt32 dwProcessId;
            public UInt32 dwThreadId;
        }

        enum SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL
        {
            SecurityAnonymous = 0,
            SecurityIdentification = 1,
            SecurityImpersonation = 2,
            SecurityDelegation = 3,
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct LUID
        {
            public Int32 LowPart;
            public Int32 HighPart;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct LUID_AND_ATRIBUTES
        {
            LUID Luid;
            Int32 Attributes;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct TOKEN_PRIVILEGES
        {
            public Int32 PrivilegeCount;
            //LUID_AND_ATRIBUTES
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
            public Int32[] Privileges;
        }

        const Int32 READ_CONTROL = 0x00020000;

        const Int32 STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0x000F0000;

        const Int32 STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ = READ_CONTROL;
        const Int32 STANDARD_RIGHTS_WRITE = READ_CONTROL;
        const Int32 STANDARD_RIGHTS_EXECUTE = READ_CONTROL;

        const Int32 STANDARD_RIGHTS_ALL = 0x001F0000;

        const Int32 SPECIFIC_RIGHTS_ALL = 0x0000FFFF;

        const Int32 TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY = 0x0001;
        const Int32 TOKEN_DUPLICATE = 0x0002;
        const Int32 TOKEN_IMPERSONATE = 0x0004;
        const Int32 TOKEN_QUERY = 0x0008;
        const Int32 TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE = 0x0010;
        const Int32 TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES = 0x0020;
        const Int32 TOKEN_ADJUST_GROUPS = 0x0040;
        const Int32 TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT = 0x0080;
        const Int32 TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID = 0x0100;

        const Int32 TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS_P = (
            STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED |
            TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY |
            TOKEN_DUPLICATE |
            TOKEN_IMPERSONATE |
            TOKEN_QUERY |
            TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE |
            TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES |
            TOKEN_ADJUST_GROUPS |
            TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT);

        const Int32 TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS = TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS_P | TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID;

        const Int32 TOKEN_READ = STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ | TOKEN_QUERY;


        const Int32 TOKEN_WRITE = STANDARD_RIGHTS_WRITE |
                                      TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES |
                                      TOKEN_ADJUST_GROUPS |
                                      TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT;

        const Int32 TOKEN_EXECUTE = STANDARD_RIGHTS_EXECUTE;

        const UInt32 MAXIMUM_ALLOWED = 0x2000000;

        const Int32 CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP = 0x00000200;
        const Int32 CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT = 0x00000400;

        const Int32 IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x40;
        const Int32 NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x20;
        const Int32 HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x80;
        const Int32 REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x100;

        const Int32 CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE = 0x00000010;

        const string SE_DEBUG_NAME = "SeDebugPrivilege";
        const string SE_RESTORE_NAME = "SeRestorePrivilege";
        const string SE_BACKUP_NAME = "SeBackupPrivilege";

        const Int32 SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED = 0x0002;

        const Int32 ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED = 1300;

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct PROCESSENTRY32
        {
            UInt32 dwSize;
            UInt32 cntUsage;
            UInt32 th32ProcessID;
            IntPtr th32DefaultHeapID;
            UInt32 th32ModuleID;
            UInt32 cntThreads;
            UInt32 th32ParentProcessID;
            Int32 pcPriClassBase;
            UInt32 dwFlags;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
            string szExeFile;
        }

        const UInt32 TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS = 0x00000002;

        const Int32 INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = -1;

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern Boolean CloseHandle(IntPtr hSnapshot);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern UInt32 WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();

        [DllImport("Wtsapi32.dll")]
        static extern UInt32 WTSQueryUserToken(UInt32 SessionId, ref IntPtr phToken);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern Boolean LookupPrivilegeValue(IntPtr lpSystemName, string lpname, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] ref LUID lpLuid);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateProcessAsUser", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        extern static Boolean CreateProcessAsUser(IntPtr hToken, String lpApplicationName, String lpCommandLine, ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes,
            ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes, Boolean bInheritHandle, Int32 dwCreationFlags, IntPtr lpEnvironment,
            String lpCurrentDirectory, ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo, out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "DuplicateTokenEx")]
        extern static Boolean DuplicateTokenEx(IntPtr ExistingTokenHandle, UInt32 dwDesiredAccess,
            ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes, Int32 TokenType,
            Int32 ImpersonationLevel, ref IntPtr DuplicateTokenHandle);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(UInt32 dwDesiredAccess, Boolean bInheritHandle, UInt32 dwProcessId);

        [DllImport("advapi32", SetLastError = true), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute]
        static extern Boolean OpenProcessToken(IntPtr ProcessHandle, // handle to process
                                            Int32 DesiredAccess, // desired access to process
                                            ref IntPtr TokenHandle); // handle to open access token

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern Boolean AdjustTokenPrivileges(IntPtr TokenHandle, Boolean DisableAllPrivileges, ref TOKEN_PRIVILEGES NewState, Int32 BufferLength, IntPtr PreviousState, IntPtr ReturnLength);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern Boolean SetTokenInformation(IntPtr TokenHandle, TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS TokenInformationClass, ref UInt32 TokenInformation, UInt32 TokenInformationLength);

        [DllImport("userenv.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern Boolean CreateEnvironmentBlock(ref IntPtr lpEnvironment, IntPtr hToken, Boolean bInherit);

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Method returns name of the user that logged in on workstation
        /// </summary>
        public static String GetLoggedInUserName()
        {
            String userName = String.Empty;

            try
            {
                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                    new ManagementObjectSearcher(cstrScope, cstrLoggenInUser);

                foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
                {
                    userName = queryObj["UserName"].ToString();
                    break;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                userName = String.Empty;
            }

            return userName;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates the process in the interactive desktop with credentials of the logged in user.
        /// </summary>
        public static Boolean CreateProcessAsUser(String commandLine, 
            String workingDirectory,
            String userAppName, 
            out StringBuilder output)
        {
            Boolean processStarted = false;
            output = new StringBuilder();

            try
            {
                UInt32 dwSessionId = WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();
                output.AppendLine(String.Format("Active console session Id: {0}", dwSessionId));

                IntPtr hUserToken = IntPtr.Zero;
                WTSQueryUserToken(dwSessionId, ref hUserToken);

                if (hUserToken != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    output.AppendLine(String.Format("WTSQueryUserToken() OK (hUserToken:{0})", hUserToken));

                    Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(userAppName);

                    if (processes.Length == 0)
                    {
                        output.AppendLine(String.Format("Application '{0}' can not be found in the running processes", userAppName));
                        return false;
                    }

                    Int32 userAppProcessId = -1;

                    for (Int32 k = 0; k < processes.Length; k++)
                    {
                        output.AppendLine(String.Format("Process: '{0}', PID: {1}, Handle: {2}, Session: {3}",
                            processes[k].ProcessName, processes[k].Id, processes[k].Handle, processes[k].SessionId));

                        if ((UInt32)processes[k].SessionId == dwSessionId)
                        {
                            userAppProcessId = processes[k].Id;
                        }
                    }

                    if (userAppProcessId == -1)
                    {
                        output.AppendLine(String.Format("Application '{0}' is not found in the processes of the current session", userAppName));
                        return false;
                    }

                    IntPtr hProcess = OpenProcess((Int32)MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, false, (UInt32)userAppProcessId);

                    IntPtr hPToken = IntPtr.Zero;

                    OpenProcessToken(hProcess,
                        TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES
                        | TOKEN_QUERY
                        | TOKEN_DUPLICATE
                        | TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY
                        | TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID
                        | TOKEN_READ
                        | TOKEN_WRITE,
                        ref hPToken);

                    if (hPToken != IntPtr.Zero)
                    {
                        output.AppendLine(String.Format("OpenProcessToken() OK (Token: {0})", hPToken));

                        LUID luid = new LUID();

                        if (LookupPrivilegeValue(IntPtr.Zero, SE_DEBUG_NAME, ref luid))
                        {
                            output.AppendLine(String.Format("LookupPrivilegeValue() OK (High: {0}, Low: {1})", luid.HighPart, luid.LowPart));

                            SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
                            sa.Length = Marshal.SizeOf(sa);

                            IntPtr hUserTokenDup = IntPtr.Zero;
                            DuplicateTokenEx(hPToken,
                                (Int32)MAXIMUM_ALLOWED,
                                ref sa,
                                (Int32)SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityIdentification,
                                (Int32)TOKEN_TYPE.TokenPrimary,
                                ref hUserTokenDup);

                            if (hUserTokenDup != IntPtr.Zero)
                            {
                                output.AppendLine(String.Format("DuplicateTokenEx() OK (hToken: {0})", hUserTokenDup));

                                TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp = new TOKEN_PRIVILEGES
                                      {
                                          PrivilegeCount = 1, 
                                        Privileges = new Int32[3]
                                      };

                                tp.Privileges[1] = luid.HighPart;
                                tp.Privileges[0] = luid.LowPart;
                                tp.Privileges[2] = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

                                //Adjust Token privilege
                                if (SetTokenInformation(hUserTokenDup,
                                    TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS.TokenSessionId,
                                    ref dwSessionId,
                                    (UInt32)IntPtr.Size))
                                {
                                    output.AppendLine(String.Format("SetTokenInformation() OK"));

                                    if (AdjustTokenPrivileges(hUserTokenDup,
                                        false, ref tp, Marshal.SizeOf(tp),
                                        IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero))
                                    {
                                        output.AppendLine("AdjustTokenPrivileges() OK");

                                        Int32 dwCreationFlags = NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE;

                                        IntPtr pEnv = IntPtr.Zero;
                                        if (CreateEnvironmentBlock(ref pEnv, hUserTokenDup, true))
                                        {
                                            dwCreationFlags |= CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            output.AppendLine(String.Format("CreateEnvironmentBlock() FAILED (Last Error: {0})", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
                                            pEnv = IntPtr.Zero;
                                        }

                                        // Launch the process in the client's logon session.
                                        PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

                                        STARTUPINFO si = new STARTUPINFO();
                                        si.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(si);
                                        si.lpDesktop = "winsta0\\default";

                                        output.AppendLine(String.Format("CreateProcess (Path:{0}, CurrDir:{1})", commandLine, workingDirectory));

                                        if (CreateProcessAsUser(hUserTokenDup,    // client's access token
                                                null,                // file to execute
                                                commandLine,        // command line
                                                ref sa,                // pointer to process SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
                                                ref sa,                // pointer to thread SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
                                                false,                // handles are not inheritable
                                                dwCreationFlags,    // creation flags
                                                pEnv,                // pointer to new environment block 
                                                workingDirectory,    // name of current directory 
                                                ref si,                // pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
                                                out pi                // receives information about new process
                                            ))
                                        {
                                            processStarted = true;
                                            output.AppendLine(String.Format("CreateProcessAsUser() OK (PID: {0})", pi.dwProcessId));
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            output.AppendLine(String.Format("CreateProcessAsUser() failed (Last Error: {0})", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        output.AppendLine(String.Format("AdjustTokenPrivileges() failed (Last Error: {0})", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    output.AppendLine(String.Format("SetTokenInformation() failed (Last Error: {0})", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
                                }

                                CloseHandle(hUserTokenDup);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                output.AppendLine(String.Format("DuplicateTokenEx() failed (Last Error: {0})", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            output.AppendLine(String.Format("LookupPrivilegeValue() failed (Last Error: {0})", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
                        }

                        CloseHandle(hPToken);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        output.AppendLine(String.Format("OpenProcessToken() failed (Last Error: {0})", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
                    }

                    CloseHandle(hUserToken);
                }
                else
                {
                    output.AppendLine(String.Format("WTSQueryUserToken failed: {0}", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                output.AppendLine("Exception occurred: " + ex.Message);
            }

            return processStarted;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
try
{            
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    if (!Win32API.CreateProcessAsUser("C:\\WINDOWS\\notepad.exe", "C:\\WINDOWS\\", "winlogon", out output))
         throw new Win32Exception(output.ToString());
    else
         throw new Win32Exception("Process RUN!!!");
}
catch (Win32Exception ex)
{
    File.WriteAllText("c:\\hello!.txt", ex.Message + " " + ex.ErrorCode.ToString());
}
```

Credits for the code goes to Forcas from rsdn.ru

Comment: Thanks Eugene, but the whole point of this, is that I want to start the process under another set of credentials, not those of the logged in user.  Similar to the runas command in xp with no uac involved.

Comment: This doesn't work on Windows 7, probably because there's no Winlogon.exe there. Plus, its quite a nasty habit to rely on file or process names.

Comment: Oh, please. It's an example and there's notepad on every Windows installation

Comment: That code is bizarre.  It starts by getting a token using WTSQueryUserToken, but never uses it.  Huh?  It goes looking for winlogon.exe in the target session, which is bad practice because that process might not exist in future versions of Windows, and takes a token from it - and *then* it goes and sets the session ID for the token to the target session.  Hello?  The token *came* from the target session.  It *already* has the right session ID.

Comment: If you're already running as local system (and this code won't work if you're not, since it calls WTSQueryUserToken) then all you have to do to run code as local system in the target session is to duplicate your *own* token and set the session ID to that of the target session.  If you want to run code in the target session as the logged on user, you can just use the token from WTSQueryUserToken.  Either way, there's no need for messing about stealing a token from another process.

Comment: Final note: the buffer size in SetTokenInformation should be `Int32.Size` not `IntPtr.Size`.

Comment: I am still confused here: Is there a difference between a userToken and a processToken to be used for DuplicateTokenEx?

Answer (score 3):

I found some old project where I used code below and it worked at the time (looks similar to yours), maybe it won't help but still it's worth a try :

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
startInfo.FileName = Application.ExecutablePath;
startInfo.Verb = "runas";
try
{
    Process p = Process.Start(startInfo);
}
catch(System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception ex)
{
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you aren't alone with this issue, and it may not be possible as you are trying to do:

http://www.icodefactory.com/lab/post/UAC-Revealed-7e-elevation-of-rights-from-NET-as-commonly-misunderstood.aspx

It's just a guess, but maybe you can request admin privileges and then [impersonate the user](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.impersonate%28VS.71%29.aspx) and then finally then start the process while impersonating?

Edit:  You can also try PInvoke which based on a comment on this page is working for starting a process under a different user:
http://blogs.msdn.com/thottams/archive/2006/08/11/696013.aspx

Comment: Thanks Purple.  Looks like I might have to give up on this.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding manifest file for that other process that you want to start. 
Windows will analyze manifest file and present you with UAC dialog before process start.

Here is the info how to embed manifest file [link1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx) and [link2](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/10/28/Windows-Vista-_2D00_-Demand-UAC-elevation-for-an-application-by-adding-a-manifest-using-mt.exe.aspx)

HTH

Comment: I have a manifest file and I get UAC dialog, but that still on lets me run under the current user's credentials.  Thanks for the response though.

Comment: Well, you can impersonate before creating new process. This link (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/cpimpersonation1.aspx) has more insights.

Comment: I will give it a try on Monday (not able to get to the system until then)... I will let you know it it works.