# RunAs running under LocalSystem C#

Tags: c#, windows, wcf, wcf-security

We are trying to execute a process, let's say "cmd.exe" under another username credentials. The application is running as a WCF service under LocalSystem account. 
We have tried several methods(Process.start, CreateProcessWithLogOn, etc) and all seem to fail with "Access denied".

Does anyone know how to do it? Is there any way out there to do it?

```
        var myProcess = new ProcessStartInfo(path)
            {
                UserName = username,
                Password = MakeSecureString(password),
                UseShellExecute = false, LoadUserProfile = true
            };
```

Comment: I'm not too clear from your question - are you trying to run this other program under the Local System account, or is your code *already* running under Local System, and you're wanting to launch the other program using another user account?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Process.Start with different credentials with UAC on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313553/process-start-with-different-credentials-with-uac-on)