# How to Start a Process Unelevated

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, elevation, process-elevation

My app runs as `requestedExecutionLevel` set to `highestAvailable`.

How do I run a process unelevated?

I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo {FileName = "foo.exe", Verb = "open"})
```

I have tried the following trust levels to start my process using Win32 API but none of them work correctly:

```
0
1260: This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system administrator.

0x1000
The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142). Click OK to close the application. 

0x10000
Process starts then hangs

0x20000
All options are not available

0x40000
Runs as admin
```

If I run `tskill foo` from my elevated app, it restarts foo with correct privileges.

What I need is a solution in which I don't have to specify the trust level. The process should start with the correct trust level automatically just like the `tskill` tool restarts `foo.exe` in the correct trust level. The user selects and runs `foo.exe` and so it can be anything.

If I can get the trust level of a process somehow, I can do this easily since `foo.exe` runs when my app can capture its trust level.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173630/how-do-you-de-elevate-privileges-for-a-child-process

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196949/how-to-run-not-elevated-in-vista-net

Comment: You are doing it the wrong way 'round. Make the master process able to run *unelevated*, and then elevate one or more child processes to perform privileged tasks. That solves this problem, and a host of others.

Comment: Also, I see you've started a bounty. Why? Do you disagree that this question is a duplicate of the one Rob suggested a year ago? What problem are you still struggling with?

Comment: @CodyGray I have updated the question. The other way round won't work for my situation, the user will have to deal with UAC tens of times.

Comment: Future readers should note that Cody's suggestion is still the best approach.  You don't need UAC approval more than once if you design the application properly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you de-elevate privileges for a child process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173630/how-do-you-de-elevate-privileges-for-a-child-process)

Answer (score 12):

The Win32 Security Management functions provide the capability to create a restricted token with normal user rights; with the token, you can call `CreateProcessAsUser` to run the process with that token.  Below is a proof of concept that runs cmd.exe as a normal user, regardless of whether the process is run in an elevated context.

```
// Initialize variables.  
IntPtr hSaferLevel, hToken;
STARTUPINFO si = default(STARTUPINFO);
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES processAttributes = default(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES threadAttributes = default(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
si.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(si);

// The process to start (for demonstration, cmd.exe)
string ProcessName = Path.Combine(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System),
    "cmd.exe");

// Create the restricted token info
if (!SaferCreateLevel(
     SaferScopes.User,
     SaferLevels.NormalUser, // Program will execute as a normal user
     1, // required
     out hSaferLevel,
     IntPtr.Zero))
         throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

// From the level create a token
if (!SaferComputeTokenFromLevel(
     hSaferLevel,
     IntPtr.Zero,
     out hToken,
     SaferComputeTokenFlags.None,
     IntPtr.Zero))
         throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

// Run the process with the restricted token
if (!CreateProcessAsUser(
     hToken,
     ProcessName,
     null, ref processAttributes, ref threadAttributes,
     true, 0, IntPtr.Zero, null,
     ref si, out pi))
         throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

 // Cleanup
 if (!CloseHandle(pi.hProcess))
     throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
 if (!CloseHandle(pi.hThread))
     throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
 if (!SaferCloseLevel(hSaferLevel))
     throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
```

This approach makes use the following Win32 functions:

- [`SaferIdentifyLevel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms722428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to indicate the identity level (limited, normal, or elevated).  Setting the `levelId` to `SAFER_LEVELID_NORMALUSER` (0x20000) provides the normal user level.
- [`SaferComputeTokenFromLevel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms722424%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) creates a token for the provided level.  Passing `NULL` to the InAccessToken parameter uses the identity of the current thread.
- [`CreateProcessAsUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) creates the process with the provided token.  Since the session is already interactive, most of the parameters can be kept at default values.  (The third parameter, `lpCommandLine` can be provided as a string to specify the command line.)
- [`CloseHandle` (Kernel32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`SaferCloseLevel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms722423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to free allocated memory.

Finally, the P/Invoke code is below (copied mostly from pinvoke.net):

```
[Flags]
public enum SaferLevels : uint
{
    Disallowed = 0,
    Untrusted = 0x1000,
    Constrained = 0x10000,
    NormalUser = 0x20000,
    FullyTrusted = 0x40000
}

[Flags]
public enum SaferComputeTokenFlags : uint
{
    None = 0x0,
    NullIfEqual = 0x1,
    CompareOnly = 0x2,
    MakeIntert = 0x4,
    WantFlags = 0x8
}

[Flags]
public enum SaferScopes : uint
{
    Machine = 1,
    User = 2
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
{
    public int nLength;
    public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
    public int bInheritHandle;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
struct STARTUPINFO
{
    public Int32 cb;
    public string lpReserved;
    public string lpDesktop;
    public string lpTitle;
    public Int32 dwX;
    public Int32 dwY;
    public Int32 dwXSize;
    public Int32 dwYSize;
    public Int32 dwXCountChars;
    public Int32 dwYCountChars;
    public Int32 dwFillAttribute;
    public Int32 dwFlags;
    public Int16 wShowWindow;
    public Int16 cbReserved2;
    public IntPtr lpReserved2;
    public IntPtr hStdInput;
    public IntPtr hStdOutput;
    public IntPtr hStdError;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
{
    public IntPtr hProcess;
    public IntPtr hThread;
    public int dwProcessId;
    public int dwThreadId;
}


[DllImport("advapi32", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern bool SaferComputeTokenFromLevel(IntPtr LevelHandle, IntPtr InAccessToken, out IntPtr OutAccessToken, int dwFlags, IntPtr lpReserved);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern bool CreateProcessAsUser(
    IntPtr hToken,
    string lpApplicationName,
    string lpCommandLine,
    ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes,
    ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
    bool bInheritHandles,
    uint dwCreationFlags,
    IntPtr lpEnvironment,
    string lpCurrentDirectory,
    ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,
    out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation); 

[DllImport("advapi32", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern bool SaferCreateLevel(
    SaferScopes dwScopeId,
    SaferLevels dwLevelId,
    int OpenFlags,
    out IntPtr pLevelHandle,
    IntPtr lpReserved);

[DllImport("advapi32", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern bool SaferCloseLevel(
    IntPtr pLevelHandle);

[DllImport("advapi32", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern bool SaferComputeTokenFromLevel(
  IntPtr levelHandle,
  IntPtr inAccessToken,
  out IntPtr outAccessToken,
  SaferComputeTokenFlags dwFlags,
  IntPtr lpReserved
);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);
```

Comment: this is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196949/how-to-run-not-elevated-in-vista-net but, if you don't need impersonation, just unelevation, then i suppose this would work. also, this should be linked somewhere: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721849%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#safer_functions

Comment: @porkchop The methodology is described (and adopted from) the C++ sample code in [Writing Secure Code, Second Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/book.aspx?ID=5957&locale=en-us), chapter 7, pp 241-243.  The C# code is original, but it simply calls 3 API calls in sequence; it's not surprising it is similar to another answer.

Comment: linking the MSDN VB.net sample project here as well: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/VBUACSelfElevation-4c014507 <- Windows UAC self-elevation

Comment: This works, but the resulting process will inherit high integrity from its parent. See my answer for additional code to start the child process with medium integrity, which is what an unelevated process would typically have.

Comment: Not sure why new tokens computed with `SaferComputeTokenFromLevel` are still marked as "elevated". Any attempt to elevate again from the resulting process will fail.

Comment: This method does not work if parent process already is elevated as commented here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196949/how-to-run-not-elevated-in-vista-net/287072#287072 The Process Hacker still shows the resulted process as `Elevation=Full`. This method works as expected: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45915599/how-can-i-unelevate-a-process/45921237#45921237

Answer (score 12):

I had best results by cloning Explorer's token as follows:

```
var shellWnd = WinAPI.GetShellWindow();
if (shellWnd == IntPtr.Zero)
    throw new Exception("Could not find shell window");

uint shellProcessId;
WinAPI.GetWindowThreadProcessId(shellWnd, out shellProcessId);

var hShellProcess = WinAPI.OpenProcess(0x00000400 /* QueryInformation */, false, shellProcessId);

var hShellToken = IntPtr.Zero;
if (!WinAPI.OpenProcessToken(hShellProcess, 2 /* TOKEN_DUPLICATE */, out hShellToken))
    throw new Win32Exception();

uint tokenAccess = 8 /*TOKEN_QUERY*/ | 1 /*TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY*/ | 2 /*TOKEN_DUPLICATE*/ | 0x80 /*TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT*/ | 0x100 /*TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID*/;
var hToken = IntPtr.Zero;
WinAPI.DuplicateTokenEx(hShellToken, tokenAccess, IntPtr.Zero, 2 /* SecurityImpersonation */, 1 /* TokenPrimary */, out hToken);

var pi = new WinAPI.PROCESS_INFORMATION();
var si = new WinAPI.STARTUPINFO();
si.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(si);
if (!WinAPI.CreateProcessWithTokenW(hToken, 0, null, cmdArgs, 0, IntPtr.Zero, null, ref si, out pi))
    throw new Win32Exception();
```

---

### Alternative approach

Originally I went with drf's excellent answer, but expanded it somewhat. If the above (clone Explorer's token) is not to your liking, keep reading but **see a gotcha at the very end**.

When using drf's method as described, the process is started without administrative access, but it still has a high integrity level. A typical un-elevated process has a medium integrity level.

Try this: use Process Hacker to see the properties of the process started this way; you will see that PH considers the process to be elevated even though it doesn't have administrative access. Add an Integrity column and you'll see it's "High".

The fix is reasonably simple: after using `SaferComputeTokenFromLevel`, we need to change the token integrity level to Medium. The code to do this might look something like this (converted from [MSDN sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625960.aspx)):

```
// Get the Medium Integrity SID
if (!WinAPI.ConvertStringSidToSid("S-1-16-8192", out pMediumIntegritySid))
    throw new Win32Exception();

// Construct a structure describing the token integrity level
var TIL = new TOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL();
TIL.Label.Attributes = 0x00000020 /* SE_GROUP_INTEGRITY */;
TIL.Label.Sid = pMediumIntegritySid;
pTIL = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf<TOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL>());
Marshal.StructureToPtr(TIL, pTIL, false);

// Modify the token
if (!WinAPI.SetTokenInformation(hToken, 25 /* TokenIntegrityLevel */, pTIL,
                                (uint) Marshal.SizeOf<TOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL>()
                                + WinAPI.GetLengthSid(pMediumIntegritySid)))
    throw new Win32Exception();
```

Alas, this still doesn't *really* solve the problem completely. The process won't have administrative access; it won't have a high integrity, but **it will *still* have a token that's marked as "elevated".**

Whether this is a problem for you or not I don't know, but it may have been why I ended up cloning Explorer's token in the end, as described at the start of this answer.

---

Here is my full source code (modified drf's answer), in all its P/Invoke glory:

```
var hSaferLevel = IntPtr.Zero;
var hToken = IntPtr.Zero;
var pMediumIntegritySid = IntPtr.Zero;
var pTIL = IntPtr.Zero;
var pi = new WinAPI.PROCESS_INFORMATION();
try
{
    var si = new WinAPI.STARTUPINFO();
    si.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(si);
    var processAttributes = new WinAPI.SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
    var threadAttributes = new WinAPI.SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
    var args = CommandRunner.ArgsToCommandLine(Args);

    if (!WinAPI.SaferCreateLevel(WinAPI.SaferScopes.User, WinAPI.SaferLevels.NormalUser, 1, out hSaferLevel, IntPtr.Zero))
        throw new Win32Exception();

    if (!WinAPI.SaferComputeTokenFromLevel(hSaferLevel, IntPtr.Zero, out hToken, WinAPI.SaferComputeTokenFlags.None, IntPtr.Zero))
        throw new Win32Exception();

    if (!WinAPI.ConvertStringSidToSid("S-1-16-8192", out pMediumIntegritySid))
        throw new Win32Exception();
    var TIL = new TOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL();
    TIL.Label.Attributes = 0x00000020 /* SE_GROUP_INTEGRITY */;
    TIL.Label.Sid = pMediumIntegritySid;
    pTIL = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf<TOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL>());
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(TIL, pTIL, false);
    if (!WinAPI.SetTokenInformation(hToken, 25 /* TokenIntegrityLevel */, pTIL, (uint) Marshal.SizeOf<TOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL>() + WinAPI.GetLengthSid(pMediumIntegritySid)))
        throw new Win32Exception();

    if (!WinAPI.CreateProcessAsUser(hToken, null, commandLine, ref processAttributes, ref threadAttributes, true, 0, IntPtr.Zero, null, ref si, out pi))
        throw new Win32Exception();
}
finally
{
    if (hToken != IntPtr.Zero && !WinAPI.CloseHandle(hToken))
        throw new Win32Exception();
    if (pMediumIntegritySid != IntPtr.Zero && WinAPI.LocalFree(pMediumIntegritySid) != IntPtr.Zero)
        throw new Win32Exception();
    if (pTIL != IntPtr.Zero)
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pTIL);
    if (pi.hProcess != IntPtr.Zero && !WinAPI.CloseHandle(pi.hProcess))
        throw new Win32Exception();
    if (pi.hThread != IntPtr.Zero && !WinAPI.CloseHandle(pi.hThread))
        throw new Win32Exception();
}
```

And here are the P/Invoke definitions you'll need in addition to those listed in drf's answer:

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern Boolean SetTokenInformation(IntPtr TokenHandle, int TokenInformationClass,
    IntPtr TokenInformation, UInt32 TokenInformationLength);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
public static extern uint GetLengthSid(IntPtr pSid);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool ConvertStringSidToSid(
    string StringSid,
    out IntPtr ptrSid);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr LocalFree(IntPtr hMem);
```

Comment: Where is the definition for `TOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL`? What is the purpose of the `var args = CommandRunner.ArgsToCommandLine(Args);` line? It would be really nice if your 'full source code' was actually the full source code so that we don't have to spend hours piecing things together from drf's answer and look for missing definitions online.

Comment: @JoeyJoeJoeJrShabadoo it would also be really nice if people took freely provided answers for what they are. I spent hours trying to figure this out. I then found some spare time to write up what I found, too. And you're still not happy. Point out the shortcoming _nicely_ and it will get fixed. Maybe even help out a little and make an edit suggestion instead of complaining?

Comment: My apologies for sounding ungrateful. I too have spent many hours giving back to SO and I know what kind of time it must have taken to craft an answer such as this. But I spent more than an hour putting your code together last night only to find out that it doesn't solve my problem. Even if your answer is "more correct" than drf's, it is incomplete and unusable. Take my criticism however you want but I still maintain that your answer here is less than helpful as it only served to waste my time. My goal with these comments is to either push you to correct it or else to warn others to stay away

Comment: @JoeyJoeJoeJrShabadoo Fair enough. FWIW, I recommend cloning Explorer's token; the other approach was way more complicated and didn't _quite_ manage to produce a token with the right properties.

Answer (score 5):

Raymond Chen addressed this in his blog:

[How can I launch an unelevated process from my elevated process and vice versa?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=2643)

Searching in GitHub for a C# version of this code, I found the following implementation in [Microsoft's](https://www.microsoft.com/) **Node.js tools for Visual Studio** repository: [SystemUtilities.cs](https://github.com/microsoft/nodejstools/blob/master/Nodejs/Product/Nodejs/SharedProject/SystemUtilities.cs) (see the `ExecuteProcessUnElevated` function).

Just in case the file disappears, here's the file's contents:

```
// Copyright (c) Microsoft.  All Rights Reserved.  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0.  See License.txt in the project root for license information.

using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Microsoft.NodejsTools.SharedProject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Utility for accessing window IShell* interfaces in order to use them to launch a process unelevated
    /// </summary>
    internal class SystemUtility
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// We are elevated and should launch the process unelevated. We can't create the
        /// process directly without it becoming elevated. So to workaround this, we have
        /// explorer do the process creation (explorer is typically running unelevated).
        /// </summary>
        internal static void ExecuteProcessUnElevated(string process, string args, string currentDirectory = "")
        {
            var shellWindows = (IShellWindows)new CShellWindows();

            // Get the desktop window
            object loc = CSIDL_Desktop;
            object unused = new object();
            int hwnd;
            var serviceProvider = (IServiceProvider)shellWindows.FindWindowSW(ref loc, ref unused, SWC_DESKTOP, out hwnd, SWFO_NEEDDISPATCH);

            // Get the shell browser
            var serviceGuid = SID_STopLevelBrowser;
            var interfaceGuid = typeof(IShellBrowser).GUID;
            var shellBrowser = (IShellBrowser)serviceProvider.QueryService(ref serviceGuid, ref interfaceGuid);

            // Get the shell dispatch
            var dispatch = typeof(IDispatch).GUID;
            var folderView = (IShellFolderViewDual)shellBrowser.QueryActiveShellView().GetItemObject(SVGIO_BACKGROUND, ref dispatch);
            var shellDispatch = (IShellDispatch2)folderView.Application;

            // Use the dispatch (which is unelevated) to launch the process for us
            shellDispatch.ShellExecute(process, args, currentDirectory, string.Empty, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Interop definitions
        /// </summary>
        private const int CSIDL_Desktop = 0;
        private const int SWC_DESKTOP = 8;
        private const int SWFO_NEEDDISPATCH = 1;
        private const int SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1;
        private const int SVGIO_BACKGROUND = 0;
        private readonly static Guid SID_STopLevelBrowser = new Guid("4C96BE40-915C-11CF-99D3-00AA004AE837");

        [ComImport]
        [Guid("9BA05972-F6A8-11CF-A442-00A0C90A8F39")]
        [ClassInterfaceAttribute(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
        private class CShellWindows
        {
        }

        [ComImport]
        [Guid("85CB6900-4D95-11CF-960C-0080C7F4EE85")]
        [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
        private interface IShellWindows
        {
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch)]
            object FindWindowSW([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] ref object pvarloc, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] ref object pvarlocRoot, int swClass, out int pHWND, int swfwOptions);
        }

        [ComImport]
        [Guid("6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa")]
        [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
        private interface IServiceProvider
        {
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)]
            object QueryService(ref Guid guidService, ref Guid riid);
        }

        [ComImport]
        [Guid("000214E2-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
        [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
        private interface IShellBrowser
        {
            void VTableGap01(); // GetWindow
            void VTableGap02(); // ContextSensitiveHelp
            void VTableGap03(); // InsertMenusSB
            void VTableGap04(); // SetMenuSB
            void VTableGap05(); // RemoveMenusSB
            void VTableGap06(); // SetStatusTextSB
            void VTableGap07(); // EnableModelessSB
            void VTableGap08(); // TranslateAcceleratorSB
            void VTableGap09(); // BrowseObject
            void VTableGap10(); // GetViewStateStream
            void VTableGap11(); // GetControlWindow
            void VTableGap12(); // SendControlMsg
            IShellView QueryActiveShellView();
        }

        [ComImport]
        [Guid("000214E3-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
        [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
        private interface IShellView
        {
            void VTableGap01(); // GetWindow
            void VTableGap02(); // ContextSensitiveHelp
            void VTableGap03(); // TranslateAcceleratorA
            void VTableGap04(); // EnableModeless
            void VTableGap05(); // UIActivate
            void VTableGap06(); // Refresh
            void VTableGap07(); // CreateViewWindow
            void VTableGap08(); // DestroyViewWindow
            void VTableGap09(); // GetCurrentInfo
            void VTableGap10(); // AddPropertySheetPages
            void VTableGap11(); // SaveViewState
            void VTableGap12(); // SelectItem

            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)]
            object GetItemObject(UInt32 aspectOfView, ref Guid riid);
        }

        [ComImport]
        [Guid("00020400-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
        [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
        private interface IDispatch
        {
        }

        [ComImport]
        [Guid("E7A1AF80-4D96-11CF-960C-0080C7F4EE85")]
        [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
        private interface IShellFolderViewDual
        {
            object Application { [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch)] get; }
        }

        [ComImport]
        [Guid("A4C6892C-3BA9-11D2-9DEA-00C04FB16162")]
        [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
        public interface IShellDispatch2
        {
            void ShellExecute([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string File, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] object vArgs, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] object vDir, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] object vOperation, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] object vShow);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution would be starting the process using *explorer.exe*. This will start any process unelevated. You can just start *explorer.exe* using

```
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start();
```

The file name will be "C:\Windows\explorer.exe" and the arguments will be the executable you want to start unelevated, surrounded by quotes.

Example:

If I wanted to start *F:\folder\example.exe* unelevated I would do this:

```
    using System.Diagnostics;

    namespace example
    {
        class exampleClass
        {
            ProcessStartInfo exampleStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            exampleStartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe";
            exampleStartInfo.Arguments = "\"F:\\folder\\example.exe\"";
            Process.Start(exampleStartInfo);
        }
    }
```

This might not work on older versions of windows, but it at least works on my laptop, so it certainly does on windows 10.

Comment: You can't you pass arguments with this method, can you? And in Windows 10 using `.BAT` files doesn't work either.

Comment: @GerardoGrignoli no, you'd need to work around for that such as some form of IPC/tcp sockets, named pipes, writing a file/registry with the args, setting clipboard text, or even creating an exe named with the (base64 of the) arguments you want and launch it (and that exe parses/un-b64 its own name and launches the actual exe)