# Specify the registry uninstall key location/hive via [Code]

Tags: inno-setup

Inno Setup by default looks at the `PrivilegesRequired` setup variable, if this is set to `admin` or `poweruser`, the installer installs the uninstall registry key to `HKLM`. If this is set to `lowest`, then it will install the registry entries to `HKCU`.

I have a requirement to provide the user an option to install for "just me" or "everybody", and have done so by replacing the dir selection page with a radio selection of these two options. what I need to do now is also modify the registry install location based on this setting. If I install the app into the local user app data, it won't make sense to register the uninstall data at the `HKLM` level, because then other users will see it in the programs list and still be unable to uninstall or use it.

**Edit:** After looking through the documentation and the source of `Install.pas`, I found the `CreateUninstallRegKey` setup directive, which will disable Inno from installing registry keys at all, after which I can add my own registry entries, but is this really the only way?

**Edit #2 (marked as duplicate):** I've already taken a look at this [Conditional Elevation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21556853/make-inno-setup-installer-request-privileges-elevation-only-when-needed) question (and actually implemented it), and it's not the same as mine. The current elevation state does ***not*** alter where Inno Setup actually saves the uninstall registry info (in HKCU or HKLM). If you look at the [Inno source code (Install.pas #507)](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/0909095f63a6a7fc48d252605fd2437416be0fdb/Projects/Install.pas#L507) you'll see that the `PrivilegesRequired` directive is the primary factor in where the registry is stored. If this is set to `lowest`, it doesnt matter if the installer is elevated or not - it will install the registry keys to HKCU, when the desired behavior is to select one or the other based on the users install preference, NOT the current elevation state. So all this being said, I'm looking for a solution to alter the registry root based on a code variable, regardless of current PrivilegesRequired or Elevation setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PrivilegesRequired=none` solution was not what I wanted. In some cases, it still prompts for elevation on administrator accounts and also the registry destination was still not reflective of the users selection.

Since I was already using a native helper DLL in my Inno Setup project, I coded this in C++ as I'm more comfortable there. I'm calling this method is called in `CurStepChanged` where `CurPage=ssDoneInstall`. Just call this method with the `[Setup]` `AppId` and whether or not the registry keys should be installed locally or not.

```c
#include <shlwapi.h>
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
bool DetectAndMoveRegKeyW(LPCWSTR app_id, bool install_local)
{
    std::wstring s_app = app_id;
    std::wstring path =
        L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\" + s_app + L"_is1";
    LPCWSTR c_path = path.c_str();

    LRESULT res;
    HKEY source = nullptr, subKey = nullptr;

    // try to find source in HKLM
    source = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    res = RegOpenKeyExW(source, c_path, 0, KEY_READ, &subKey);
    if (subKey != nullptr)
        RegCloseKey(subKey);

    // try to find source in HKCU
    if (res != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        subKey = nullptr;
        source = HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
        res = RegOpenKeyExW(source, c_path, 0, KEY_READ, &subKey);
        if (subKey != nullptr)
            RegCloseKey(subKey);
    }

    if (res != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        return false; // cant find the registry key

    HKEY dest = install_local ? HKEY_CURRENT_USER : HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    if (source == dest)
        return true; // registry already in the right place


    // copy registry key to correct destination
    HKEY hOldKey;
    HKEY hNewKey;
    bool bResult = false;
    if (RegOpenKeyW(source, c_path, &hOldKey) == 0)
    {
        if (RegCreateKeyW(dest, c_path, &hNewKey) == 0)
        {
            bResult = (SHCopyKeyW(hOldKey, nullptr, hNewKey, 0) == 0);
            RegCloseKey(hNewKey);
        }
        RegCloseKey(hOldKey);

        if (bResult)
        {
            RegDeleteKeyW(source, c_path);
        }
    }

    return bResult;
}
```

I'm exporting this method as `cdecl` instead of `stdcall`, this is because VC++ ignores the C extern and mangles method names anyways when using `stdcall`. You'll need to import this as `cdecl` in inno [(see inno docs for this)](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptdll). Also, of course this is the Unicode-only implementation, if you require an Ansi version it should be simple enough.

**IMPORTANT NOTICE:** 
This code is incomplete, it doesn't account for 64bit registry redirection. Inno-Setup completely ignores windows registry redirection and this code doesn't search the 64 bit registry at all since Inno and itself are running in 32bit.

Answer (score 2):

Inno Setup 6 has a built-in support for [selecting between "Install for all users" and "Install for me only"](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=admininstallmode).

Basically, you can simply set [`PrivilegesRequiredOverridesAllowed`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_privilegesrequiredoverridesallowed):

```
[Setup]
PrivilegesRequiredOverridesAllowed=commandline dialog
```

[image]

---

For Inno Setup 5: As you found yourself, the logic is hard-coded. You cannot really control that.

The closest you can get is by using the undocumented (deprecated) `PrivilegesRequired=none`.

With this value (and with a help of installer-autodetection in Windows):

- When you start the installer with an un-privileged account, it starts without prompting you for elevation. If you decide you need to elevate during the installation, you can [restart the installer elevated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21556853/850848).
- When you start the installer with a privileged account, it always prompts you for elevation and won't start, if you reject that. So the installer always runs elevated. Again, you would have to restart the installer, if you decide you to proceed un-elevated. See [How to Start a Process Unelevated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17765568/850848) or maybe [Run un-elevated command from an elevated prompt?](https://superuser.com/q/882075/213663).

It's not exactly, what you want, but I do not think you can get any closer.

---

You can of course copy (move) the registry key between the `HKCU` and `HKLM` yourself by a code:

```pascal
function MoveHKCUUninstallKeyToHKLM: Boolean;
var
  UninstallKey: string;
  AppId: string;
  I: Integer;
  ValueNames: TArrayOfString;
  ValueName: string;
  ValueStr: string;
  ValueDWord: Cardinal;
begin
  if '{#emit SetupSetting("AppId")}' <> '' then
  begin
    AppId := '{#emit SetupSetting("AppId")}';
  end
    else
  begin
    AppId := '{#emit SetupSetting("AppName")}';
  end;

  Result := False;
  if AppId = '' then
  begin
    Log('Cannot identify AppId');
  end
    else
  begin
    UninstallKey :=
      'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\' + AppId + '_is1';
    Log(Format(
      'AppId identified as "%s", using uninstall key "%s"', [AppId, UninstallKey]));
    if not RegKeyExists(HKCU, UninstallKey) then
    begin
      Log('HKCU uninstall key not found');
    end
      else
    if RegKeyExists(HKLM, UninstallKey) then
    begin
      Log('HKLM uninstall key exists already');
    end
      else
    begin
      Log('HKCU uninstall key found and HKLM key not exists yet');

      if not RegGetValueNames(HKCU, UninstallKey, ValueNames) then
      begin
        Log('Cannot list uninstall key values');
      end
        else
      begin
        I := 0;
        Result := True;
        while (I < GetArrayLength(ValueNames)) and Result do
        begin
          ValueName := ValueNames[I];
          if RegQueryStringValue(HKCU, UninstallKey, ValueName, ValueStr) then
          begin
            if not RegWriteStringValue(HKLM, UninstallKey, ValueName, ValueStr) then
            begin
              Log(Format('Error moving "%s" string value', [ValueName]));
              Result := False;
            end
              else
            begin
              Log(Format('Moved "%s" string value', [ValueName]));
            end;
          end
            else
          if RegQueryDWordValue(HKCU, UninstallKey, ValueName, ValueDWord) then
          begin
            if not RegWriteDWordValue(HKLM, UninstallKey, ValueName, ValueDWord) then
            begin
              Log(Format('Error moving "%s" dword value', [ValueName]));
              Result := False;
            end
              else
            begin
              Log(Format('Moved "%s" dword value', [ValueName]));
            end;
          end
            else
          begin
            { All uninstall values written by Inno Setup are either string or dword }
            Log(Format('Value "%s" is neither string nor dword', [ValueName]));
            Result := False;
          end;
          Inc(I);
        end;

        if Result then
        begin
          if not RegDeleteKeyIncludingSubkeys(HKCU, UninstallKey) then
          begin
            Log('Error removing HKCU uninstall key');
            Result := False;
          end
            else
          begin
            Log('Removed HKCU uninstall key');
          end;
        end;

        if not Result then
        begin
          if not RegDeleteKeyIncludingSubkeys(HKCU, UninstallKey) then
          begin
            Log('Failed to move uninstall key to HKLM, ' +
                'and also failed to rollback the changes');
          end
            else
          begin
            Log('Failed to move uninstall key to HKLM, rolled back the changes');
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then
  begin
    Log('Post install');
    MoveHKCUUninstallKeyToHKLM;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You're of course correct. I was thinking I'd have to re-implement the registry writing myself, I hadn't thought to simply copy them to the correct place. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction and see my answer for how I did it!

Comment: See my edited answer for a native Inno Setup solution.

Comment: I didn't test, but it looks nice. I've already integrated the registry stuff with my native solution and coded detection for whether the app being installed is x64 or x86 with the keys being put into the right view (i see your solution also ignores this problem). Anyways, Thanks for this! Both answers will be valuable for anyone finding this question in the future.