# Dynamically choose between per-user and per-machine installation

Tags: windows, deployment, admin, inno-setup, non-admin

I'm using Inno Setup to deploy an application.

For most cases, a per-user installation that doesn't require admin privileges is fine. However, there are scenarios where I need to install the app for all users, e.g. for Citrix or TSE.

Unfortunately it doesn't seem possible to choose dynamically between per-user and per-machine install. It depends on the [`PrivilegesRequired`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_privilegesrequired.htm) setting, which is set at compile time.

My latest workaround attempt almost got me there. Basically I have a setup with `PrivilegesRequired` set to `lowest`, and if I need to install for all users, I restart the setup with admin privileges. This works, **BUT** the uninstall information is still written to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` rather than `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`.

My questions:
- is there a way to achieve dual per-user/per-machine install with Inno Setup? (without generating two different installers)
- if not, is there a way to write uninstall info to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` when `PrivilegesRequired` is set to `lowest`?

EDIT: the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21556853/make-inno-setup-installer-request-privileges-elevation-only-when-needed) doesn't apply in my case. I want to request UAC elevation only when a specific argument (`/AllUsers`) is passed on the command line. Without this argument, the UAC prompt shouldn't appear even if the user is an admin. And TLama's answer has the same problem as my current approach.

Comment: Use `PrivilegesRequired=none` instead of the `lowest`.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I'll give it a try, but does it write to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` when running as admin and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` when running as non-admin?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl ok, that won't help. I want to run elevated only when a specific argument is passed on the command line. I don't want the UAC prompt to pop up, even for an admin user, unless they passed this argument. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Than, see this: [Specify the registry uninstall key location/hive via \[Code\]](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37221915/850848) (particularly the second part of [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37224058/850848)).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl thanks. I thought of doing this, but it seemed unelegant. Also, InnoSetup won't know look at the key in HKLM when I run the setup again, which is annoying...

Comment: There's no elegant solution to this problem + Why would not the setup look to HKLM? It always looks both to the HKCU and HKLM (in this order), no matter what.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, ah, good to know. I thought it looked only in HKCU when PrivilegesRequired was set to lowest.

Comment: You are welcome.