# Inno Setup: remapping of registry hives

Tags: registry, inno-setup, dllregistration

Wondering whether there is some way that I wasn't aware of, for Inno Setup to redirect hive constants. More specifically, the ability to invoke, before writing to registry, this function: [RegOverridePredefKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724901(v=vs.85).aspx).

To provide a little background, this would be, in my case, the preferred way to force a self-registering DLL to register for the current user (that may not have administrator credentials), instead of globally. (In other words, write to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes` instead of `HKCR`.) Haven't found any other Inno Setup construct that would help with this, and I would avoid using [3rd party tools](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3505/RegSvrEx-An-Enchanced-COM-Server-Registration-Util), that would also need updating, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Inno Setup does not support this.

But it's not that difficult to call it from Pascal Scripting.

Though note that you cannot use [`RegOverridePredefKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regoverridepredefkey) to redirect `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`. You can only redirect it to a subkey:

> hNewHKey: ... A handle to an open registry key. This handle is returned by the `RegCreateKeyEx` or `RegOpenKeyEx` function. **It cannot be one of the predefined keys.**

So after registering the DLL, you would have to copy the subkey to the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` and delete it (as the documentation for `RegOverridePredefKey` suggests).

Basic code for redirecting to a temporary subkey:

```pascal
[Files]
Source: "MyDllServer.dll"; Flags: ignoreversion dontcopy

[Code]

const
  KEY_WRITE = $20006;
  
function RegOverridePredefKey(Key: Integer; NewKey: Integer): Integer;
  external 'RegOverridePredefKey@advapi32.dll stdcall';

function RegCreateKeyEx(
  Key: Integer; SubKey: string; Reserved: Cardinal; Cls: Cardinal;
  Options: Cardinal; Desired: Cardinal; SecurityAttributes: Cardinal;
  var KeyResult: Integer; var Disposition: Cardinal): Integer;
  external 'RegCreateKeyExW@advapi32.dll stdcall';

function MyDllRegisterServer: Integer;
  external 'DllRegisterServer@files:MyDllServer.dll stdcall delayload';

// ...
begin
  // Create a subkey to redirect the HKLM to
  RegCreateKeyEx(
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 'MyProgTemp', 0, 0, 0, KEY_WRITE, 0, NewKey, Unused);
  // Redirect HKLM to the created subkey
  RegOverridePredefKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, NewKey);
  // Call DllRegisterServer of the .dll
  MyDllRegisterServer;
  // Now you can copy the subkey to HKCU
end;
```

Add some error handling!

The code is for Unicode version of Inno Setup.

---

For the copying part, you can reuse (and improve) my code from [Specify the registry uninstall key location/hive via [Code]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37221915/850848#37224058).

Comment: Thank you, including the highlighted observation as well. I managed to miss that somehow.