# launching an application in non administrative mode from another app running in administrative mode in server 2003 in c++

Tags: c++, windows-server-2003

[image]

Please tell me how to launch myapplication in  non administarative mode

[How to Start a Process Unelevated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17765568/how-to-start-a-process-unelevated)

Example is in c# please referer it

Comment: Please refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And don't forget how to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: This may not be possible on windows server 2003, as it predates UAC and thus the concept of process level administrator privileges.

Comment: Would running as a non-admin user work?

Comment: we want to get clipboard update to an app , which will be launched from a admin app

Comment: @user1937198 : Yes I  want to get clipboard update to an app , which will be launched from a admin app