# Start Process as administrator

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an application(called 'Launcher'), where i can start other applications

One of this applications needs administrator-rights. If i try to launch it from the Launcher i get an exception, which says that i need higher privilege.

The code to start an application from the Launcher looks like:

```
try
{
   ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(PATH, ARGUMENT)
      {
         WorkingDirectory = WORKINGDIRECTORY
      };
   Process.Start(startInfo);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

If I start the Launcher everything works fine. But I don't want to start the Launcher as administrator every time.

How can I start the new process as administrator from a non-admin-process?

Comment: Have you looked into the app.manifest files? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx

Comment: The solution with setting the Verb to "runas" doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application needs to be admin or you need to provide a username password. For the username/password approach see:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.csharp/u5YuEz416R8/1oTRvUUzKj4J

And this has more of an approach you are looking for, but it's not a nice small snippet of code as you may like.

[Process.Start with different credentials with UAC on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313553/process-start-with-different-credentials-with-uac-on)

Otherwise, add this to your app manifest file.

```
 <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Comment: But i don't want to run the Launcher always as administrator.

Comment: For security reasons, you can't do that without providing the username and password to the admin account. Only if the original application is admin can you use the runas verb.

Comment: I thought it would be possible to start the other application as adminsitrator and then the uac-message appears?

Comment: Check my edited post. I posted links on alternative methods of doing this. None of them are very pretty though.

Answer (score 0):

Create an account with admin rights and then populate the `UserName` and `Password` properties on the `ProcessStartInfo` instance with the corresponding values for the admin account.

Comment: I can not create accounts, because the tool is executed at other computers in the network.