# UAC Prompt...still not elevated

Tags: c#, uac

I am using this code to elevate an app.  The UAC prompt shows just fine.  Checking `isAdministrator()` states the app is *not* elevated...?  Is this possible?

```
    public static bool IsAdministrator()
    {
        WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();

        if (null != identity)
        {
            WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
            return principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static Process RunProcess(string name, string arguments)
    {
        string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(name);

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
        {
            path = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        }

        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            UseShellExecute = true,
            WorkingDirectory = path,
            FileName = name,
            Arguments = arguments
        };

        if (!IsAdministrator())
        {
            info.Verb = "runas";
        }

        try
        {
            return Process.Start(info);
        }

        catch (Win32Exception ex)
        {
            //Trace.WriteLine(ex);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Process.Start with different credentials with UAC on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313553/process-start-with-different-credentials-with-uac-on)

Comment: The code in `IsAdministrator` works fine. When executed in a process that is elevated, it will return `true`.

Comment: You should use ProcessExplorer to view the security token associate to your application

Comment: This link states that Process Explorer cannot do that ...[yet]http://forum.sysinternals.com/look-at-threads-security-token_topic4882.html

Comment: You don't need to look at the security token of a thread but of your process so Process Explorer is OK

Comment: You elevated the *other* process.  Not your own.