# Windows Service fails to start interactive process on user log on with WTSQueryUserToken for some versions of Windows

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services, interopservices

Following this [link](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CSCreateProcessAsUserFromSe-b682134e), I have implemented **WTSQueryUserToken** in my C# solution and called the `CreateProcessAsUserWrapper.LaunchChildProcess("app_path")` method from the `OnStart` of my Windows Service which is made to run as **"LocalSystem"**. It is able to start the process which can interact with desktop, but for Windows Professional and not for Windows Ultimate. I tried it on Windows Professional 64 bit and it is able to successfully start the process on user log on interactively, but on Windows Ultimate 64 bit version the **`CreateProcessAsUser` method is returning false** and the service can be seen running at `SCM` whereas the process is not.

My process is a win form app which needs to run with currently logged on user account for desktop interaction and uses the `InteropServices`. Can it be a framework issue? How to get to the problem? Please help.

***Edit:***
Both the machines are running Windows 7 64-bit. I added the following code to get the error code after `CreateProcessAsUser` and **it returns "The requested operation requires elevation" as error.**

```
string errorMessage = new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message;
```

It is happening only in Windows 7 Ultimate and not in Windows 7 Professional. I need to run my process for every logged on user and that is why I think I can't use the `CreateProcessWithLogonW` method instead. How can I fix this elevation privilege issue now?

***Edit:***
There was 2 `app.manifest` files, one inside the service project and the other inside the win form (process) project. I removed both the files, built the `msi` with `WiX` and tested again. Now it is successfully running on every machine, the process being started with every logged on user account.  But, one problem is caused now. Actually I need to write some log under the windows/system folder, which I can't do now. I am getting "`UnauthorizedAccessException`" thrown from the process. Moreover, no user except administrator is allowed to stop or uninstall the process, but in this case a user can start the Task Manager and end the process from there since it is running with the corresponding user account. Is it possible to run the process with the user account but with elevated privilege, so that I can write my log under windows/system folder and prevent the user from stopping the process without admin permission? At least resolving the first issue i.e writing log files under system folder is very important for me.

***Edit:***
After adding `SetTokenInformation` along with `DuplicateTokenEx` my service fails to start the app with the log *"`SetTokenInformation()` returns FALSE. ERROR: A required privilege is not held by the client"*. I am providing the full code, please see if I have updated it correctly with all the steps.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; // DllImport

namespace CSCreateProcessAsUserFromService
{
    class CreateProcessAsUserWrapper1
    {
        static String tmp_log = Path.Combine(CreateDirectoryAtSystemFolder(), "Temp-Report-Service.txt");
        static string errorMessage;

        public static void LaunchChildProcess(string ChildProcName)
        {
            IntPtr ppSessionInfo = IntPtr.Zero;
            UInt32 SessionCount = 0;

            File.AppendAllText(tmp_log, "\n" + "LaunchChildProcess() OK 1" + "\n");

            if (WTSEnumerateSessions(
                (IntPtr)WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE,  // Current RD Session Host Server handle would be zero.
                0,                                  // This reserved parameter must be zero.
                1,                                  // The version of the enumeration request must be 1.
                ref ppSessionInfo,                  // This would point to an array of session info.
                ref SessionCount                    // This would indicate the length of the above array.
                ))
            {
                File.AppendAllText(tmp_log, "\n" + "WTSEnumerateSessions OK 2" + "\n");

                for (int nCount = 0; nCount < SessionCount; nCount++)
                {
                    // Extract each session info and check if it is the 
                    // "Active Session" of the current logged-on user.
                    //ppSessionInfo = new IntPtr(ppSessionInfo.ToInt32() + nCount * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WTS_SESSION_INFO)));
                    WTS_SESSION_INFO tSessionInfo = (WTS_SESSION_INFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure(
                        ppSessionInfo + nCount * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WTS_SESSION_INFO)),
                        typeof(WTS_SESSION_INFO)
                        );
                    /*WTS_SESSION_INFO tSessionInfo = (WTS_SESSION_INFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure(
                        new IntPtr(ppSessionInfo.ToInt32() + nCount * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WTS_SESSION_INFO))),
                        typeof(WTS_SESSION_INFO)
                        );*/

                    if (WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS.WTSActive == tSessionInfo.State)
                    {
                        WindowsIdentity m_ImpersonatedUser;

                        IntPtr hToken = IntPtr.Zero;
                        IntPtr hTokenDuplicate = IntPtr.Zero;
                        const int SecurityImpersonation = 2;
                        const int TokenType = 1;

                        File.AppendAllText(tmp_log, "\n" + "if (WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS.WTSActive == tSessionInfo.State) 3" + "\n");

                        if (RevertToSelf())
                        {
                            File.AppendAllText(tmp_log, "\n" + "RevertToSelf() TRUE 4 " + "\n");

                            if (WTSQueryUserToken(tSessionInfo.SessionID, out hToken))
                            {
                                File.AppendAllText(tmp_log, "\n" + "if (WTSQueryUserToken(tSessionInfo.SessionID, out hToken)) TRUE 5 " + "\n");

                                LUID luid = new LUID();
                                // Security attibute structure used in DuplicateTokenEx and CreateProcessAsUser
                                // I would prefer to not have to use a security attribute variable and to just 
                                // simply pass null and inherit (by default) the security attributes
                                // of the existing token. However, in C# structures are value types and therefore
                                // cannot be assigned the null value.
                                SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
                                sa.Length = Marshal.SizeOf(sa);
                                //if (DuplicateToken(hToken, SecurityImpersonation, ref hTokenDuplicate) != 0)
                                if (DuplicateTokenEx(hToken, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED/*GENERIC_ACCESS*/, ref sa,
                                    (int)SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityIdentification,
                                    (int)TOKEN_TYPE.TokenPrimary, out/*ref*/ hTokenDuplicate))
                                {
                                    File.AppendAllText(tmp_log, "\n" + " DuplicateTokenEx() TRUE 6 " + "\n");

                                    WindowsImpersonationContext m_ImpersonationContext;
                                    m_ImpersonatedUser = new WindowsIdentity(hTokenDuplicate);
                                    using (m_ImpersonationContext = m_ImpersonatedUser.Impersonate())
                                    {
                                        if (m_ImpersonationContext != null)
                                        {
                                            File.AppendAllText(tmp_log, Environment.NewLine + "User Name: " +
                                                      WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(TokenAccessLevels.MaximumAllowed).Name +
                                                      Environment.NewLine + "SID: " +
                                                      WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(TokenAccessLevels.MaximumAllowed).User.Value);

                                            TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp = new TOKEN_PRIVILEGES
                                            {
                                                PrivilegeCount = 1,
                                                Privileges = new Int32[3]
                                            };

                                            tp.Privileges[1] = luid.HighPart;
                                            tp.Privileges[0] = luid.LowPart;
                                            tp.Privileges[2] = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

                                            //Adjust Token privilege
                                            if (SetTokenInformation(hTokenDuplicate,
                                                TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS.TokenSessionId,
                                                ref tSessionInfo.SessionID,
                                                (UInt32)Marshal.SizeOf(tSessionInfo.SessionID)))
                                            {
                                                File.AppendAllText(tmp_log, "\n" + " SetTokenInformation() TRUE 7 " + "\n");

                                                if (AdjustTokenPrivileges(hTokenDuplicate,
                                                   false, ref tp, Marshal.SizeOf(tp),
                                                   IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero))
                                                {
                                                    File.AppendAllText(tmp_log, "\n" + " AdjustTokenPrivileges() TRUE 8 " + "\n");

                                                    //ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(hToken);
                                                    //WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(hToken);

                                                    //errorMessage = new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message;
                                                    //File.AppendAllText(tmp_log, "\n" + "LaunchChildProcess-ImpersonateLoggedOnUser-" + errorMessage + "\n");

                                                    // Launch the child process interactively 
                                                    // with the token of the logged-on user.
                                                    PROCESS_INFORMATION tProcessInfo;
                                                    STARTUPINFO tStartUpInfo = new STARTUPINFO();
                                                    tStartUpInfo.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(STARTUPINFO));
                                                    tStartUpInfo.lpDesktop = @"winsta0\default"; // interactive window station parameter; basically this indicates that the process created can display a GUI on the desktop

                                                    // flags that specify the priority and creation method of the process
                                                    int dwCreationFlags = NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE;
                                                    IntPtr pEnv = IntPtr.Zero;
                                                    if (CreateEnvironmentBlock(ref pEnv, hTokenDuplicate, true))
                                                    {
                                                        dwCreationFlags |= CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT;
                                                        File.AppendAllText(tmp_log, "\n" + " CreateEnvironmentBlock() TRUE 9 " + "\n");
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        pEnv = IntPtr.Zero;
                                                        File.AppendAllText(tmp_log, "\n" + " CreateEnvironmentBlock() ELSE 9 " + "\n");
                                                    }
                                                    // create a new process in the current user's logon session
                                                    bool ChildProcStarted = CreateProcessAsUser(
                                                        hTokenDuplicate,        // client's access token
                                                        ChildProcName,          // file to execute
                                                        null,                   // command line
                                                        ref sa,                 // pointer to process SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
                                                        ref sa,                 // pointer to thread SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
                                                        false,                  // handles are not inheritable
                                                        dwCreationFlags,        // creation flags
                                                        IntPtr.Zero,            // pointer to new environment block 
                                                        null,                   // name of current directory 
                                                        ref tStartUpInfo,                 // pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
                                                        out tProcessInfo            // receives information about new process
                                                        );

                                                    /*bool ChildProcStarted = CreateProcessAsUser(
                                                       //hToken,             // Token of the logged-on user.
                                                       hTokenDuplicate,    // Token of the logged-on user.
                                                       ChildProcName,      // Name of the process to be started.
                                                       null,               // Any command line arguments to be passed.
                                                       IntPtr.Zero,        // Default Process' attributes.
                                                       IntPtr.Zero,        // Default Thread's attributes.
                                                       false,              // Does NOT inherit parent's handles.
                                                       0,                  // No any specific creation flag.
                                                       null,               // Default environment path.
                                                       null,               // Default current directory.
                                                       ref tStartUpInfo,   // Process Startup Info. 
                                                       out tProcessInfo    // Process information to be returned.
                                                       );*/

                                                    errorMessage = new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message;
                                                    File.AppendAllText(tmp_log, "\n" + "LaunchChildProcess-CreateProcessAsUser-" + errorMessage + "\n");

                                                    if (ChildProcStarted)
                                                    {
                                                        // The child process creation is successful!

                                                        // If the child process is created, it can be controlled via the out 
                                                        // param "tProcessInfo". For now, as we don't want to do any thing 
                                                        // with the child process, closing the child process' handles 
                                                        // to prevent the handle leak.
                                                        CloseHandle(tProcessInfo.hThread);
                                                        CloseHandle(tProcessInfo.hProcess);

                                                        File.AppendAllText(tmp_log, "\n" + "ChildProcStarted() 10 true!" + "\n");
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        // CreateProcessAsUser failed!
                                                        errorMessage = new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message;
                                                        File.AppendAllText(tmp_log, "\n" + " ChildProcStarted() 10 failed! ERROR: " + errorMessage + "\n");
                                                    }

                                                    // Whether child process was created or not, close the token handle 
                                                    // and break the loop as processing for current active user has been done.
                                                    CloseHandle(hToken);
                                                    CloseHandle(hTokenDuplicate);
                                                    // Undo impersonation
                                                    //m_ImpersonationContext.Undo();
                                                    break;
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    errorMessage = new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message;
                                                    File.AppendAllText(tmp_log, "\n" + " AdjustTokenPrivileges() FALSE 8 ERROR: " + errorMessage + "\n");
                                                }
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                errorMessage = new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message;
                                                //File.AppendAllText(tmp_log, "\n" + "LaunchChildProcess-ImpersonateLoggedOnUser-" + errorMessage + "\n");
                                                File.AppendAllText(tmp_log, "\n" + " SetTokenInformation() FALSE 7 ERROR: " + errorMessage + "\n");
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    errorMessage = new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message;
                                    File.AppendAllText(tmp_log, "\n" + "DuplicateTokenEx() FALSE 6 ERROR: " + errorMessage + "\n");
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // WTSQueryUserToken failed!
                                errorMessage = new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message;
                                File.AppendAllText(tmp_log, "\n" + "if (WTSQueryUserToken(tSessionInfo.SessionID, out hToken)) FALSE 5 ERROR: " + errorMessage + "\n");
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            errorMessage = new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message;
                            File.AppendAllText(tmp_log, "\n" + "RevertToSelf() FALSE 4 ERROR: " + errorMessage + "\n");

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // This Session is not active!
                        errorMessage = new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message;
                        File.AppendAllText(tmp_log, "\n" + "if (WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS.WTSActive == tSessionInfo.State) FALSE 3 This Session is not active! ERROR: " + errorMessage + "\n");
                    }
                }

                // Free the memory allocated for the session info array.
                WTSFreeMemory(ppSessionInfo);
            }
            else
            {
                // WTSEnumerateSessions failed!
                errorMessage = new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message;
                File.AppendAllText(tmp_log, "\n" + "WTSEnumerateSessions FAILED 2 ERROR: " + errorMessage + "\n");
            }
        }


        #region P/Invoke WTS APIs
        /// <summary>
        /// Struct, Enum and P/Invoke Declarations of WTS APIs.
        /// </summary>
        /// 

        private const int WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE = 0;
        private enum WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS
        {
            WTSActive,
            WTSConnected,
            WTSConnectQuery,
            WTSShadow,
            WTSDisconnected,
            WTSIdle,
            WTSListen,
            WTSReset,
            WTSDown,
            WTSInit
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private struct WTS_SESSION_INFO
        {
            public UInt32 SessionID;
            public string pWinStationName;
            public WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS State;
        }

        [DllImport("WTSAPI32.DLL", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern bool WTSEnumerateSessions(
            IntPtr hServer,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] UInt32 Reserved,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] UInt32 Version,
            ref IntPtr ppSessionInfo,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] ref UInt32 pSessionInfoCount
            );

        [DllImport("WTSAPI32.DLL", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern void WTSFreeMemory(IntPtr pMemory);

        [DllImport("WTSAPI32.DLL", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern bool WTSQueryUserToken(UInt32 sessionId, out IntPtr Token);
        #endregion


        #region P/Invoke CreateProcessAsUser
        /// <summary>
        /// Struct, Enum and P/Invoke Declarations for CreateProcessAsUser.
        /// </summary>
        /// 

        #region WMI Constants

        private const String cstrScope = "root\\CIMV2";
        private const String cstrLoggenInUser = "SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem";

        #endregion

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public struct STARTUPINFO
        {
            public Int32 cb;
            public string lpReserved;
            public string lpDesktop;
            public string lpTitle;
            public Int32 dwX;
            public Int32 dwY;
            public Int32 dwXSize;
            public Int32 dwYSize;
            public Int32 dwXCountChars;
            public Int32 dwYCountChars;
            public Int32 dwFillAttribute;
            public Int32 dwFlags;
            public Int16 wShowWindow;
            public Int16 cbReserved2;
            public IntPtr lpReserved2;
            public IntPtr hStdInput;
            public IntPtr hStdOutput;
            public IntPtr hStdError;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
        {
            public IntPtr hProcess;
            public IntPtr hThread;
            public int dwProcessId;
            public int dwThreadId;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
        {
            public int Length;
            public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
            public bool bInheritHandle;
        }

        #region Enumerations

        enum TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS
        {
            TokenUser = 1,
            TokenGroups,
            TokenPrivileges,
            TokenOwner,
            TokenPrimaryGroup,
            TokenDefaultDacl,
            TokenSource,
            TokenType,
            TokenImpersonationLevel,
            TokenStatistics,
            TokenRestrictedSids,
            TokenSessionId,
            TokenGroupsAndPrivileges,
            TokenSessionReference,
            TokenSandBoxInert,
            TokenAuditPolicy,
            TokenOrigin,
            MaxTokenInfoClass  // MaxTokenInfoClass should always be the last enum
        }


        enum TOKEN_TYPE : int
        {
            TokenPrimary = 1,
            TokenImpersonation = 2
        }

        enum SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL : int
        {
            SecurityAnonymous = 0,
            SecurityIdentification = 1,
            SecurityImpersonation = 2,
            SecurityDelegation = 3,
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct LUID
        {
            public Int32 LowPart;
            public Int32 HighPart;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct LUID_AND_ATRIBUTES
        {
            LUID Luid;
            Int32 Attributes;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct TOKEN_PRIVILEGES
        {
            public Int32 PrivilegeCount;
            //LUID_AND_ATRIBUTES
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
            public Int32[] Privileges;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Constants

        public const uint GENERIC_ACCESS = 0x1000000;
        public const uint MAXIMUM_ALLOWED = 0x2000000;
        public const int CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE = 0x00000010;

        public const int IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x40;
        public const int NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x20;
        public const int HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x80;
        public const int REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x100;

        const Int32 READ_CONTROL = 0x00020000;

        const Int32 STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0x000F0000;

        const Int32 STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ = READ_CONTROL;
        const Int32 STANDARD_RIGHTS_WRITE = READ_CONTROL;
        const Int32 STANDARD_RIGHTS_EXECUTE = READ_CONTROL;

        const Int32 STANDARD_RIGHTS_ALL = 0x001F0000;

        const Int32 SPECIFIC_RIGHTS_ALL = 0x0000FFFF;

        const Int32 TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY = 0x0001;
        const Int32 TOKEN_DUPLICATE = 0x0002;
        const Int32 TOKEN_IMPERSONATE = 0x0004;
        const Int32 TOKEN_QUERY = 0x0008;
        const Int32 TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE = 0x0010;
        const Int32 TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES = 0x0020;
        const Int32 TOKEN_ADJUST_GROUPS = 0x0040;
        const Int32 TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT = 0x0080;
        const Int32 TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID = 0x0100;

        const Int32 TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS_P = (
            STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED |
            TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY |
            TOKEN_DUPLICATE |
            TOKEN_IMPERSONATE |
            TOKEN_QUERY |
            TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE |
            TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES |
            TOKEN_ADJUST_GROUPS |
            TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT);

        const Int32 TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS = TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS_P | TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID;

        const Int32 TOKEN_READ = STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ | TOKEN_QUERY;


        const Int32 TOKEN_WRITE = STANDARD_RIGHTS_WRITE |
                                      TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES |
                                      TOKEN_ADJUST_GROUPS |
                                      TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT;

        const Int32 TOKEN_EXECUTE = STANDARD_RIGHTS_EXECUTE;

        //const UInt32 MAXIMUM_ALLOWED = 0x2000000;

        const Int32 CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP = 0x00000200;
        const Int32 CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT = 0x00000400;

        /*const Int32 IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x40;
        const Int32 NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x20;
        const Int32 HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x80;
        const Int32 REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x100;*/

        //const Int32 CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE = 0x00000010;

        const string SE_DEBUG_NAME = "SeDebugPrivilege";
        const string SE_RESTORE_NAME = "SeRestorePrivilege";
        const string SE_BACKUP_NAME = "SeBackupPrivilege";

        const Int32 SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED = 0x0002;

        const Int32 ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED = 1300;

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct PROCESSENTRY32
        {
            UInt32 dwSize;
            UInt32 cntUsage;
            UInt32 th32ProcessID;
            IntPtr th32DefaultHeapID;
            UInt32 th32ModuleID;
            UInt32 cntThreads;
            UInt32 th32ParentProcessID;
            Int32 pcPriClassBase;
            UInt32 dwFlags;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
            string szExeFile;
        }

        const UInt32 TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS = 0x00000002;

        const Int32 INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = -1;

        #endregion

        /* [DllImport("ADVAPI32.DLL", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern bool CreateProcessAsUser(
            IntPtr hToken,
            string lpApplicationName,
            string lpCommandLine,
            IntPtr lpProcessAttributes,
            IntPtr lpThreadAttributes,
            bool bInheritHandles,
            uint dwCreationFlags,
            string lpEnvironment,
            string lpCurrentDirectory,
            ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,
            out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation
            );*/

         [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateProcessAsUser", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
         public extern static bool CreateProcessAsUser(IntPtr hToken, String lpApplicationName, String lpCommandLine, ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes,
             ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes, bool bInheritHandle, int dwCreationFlags, IntPtr lpEnvironment,
             String lpCurrentDirectory, ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo, out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);

        [DllImport("KERNEL32.DLL", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hHandle);
        #endregion

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern UInt32 WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern Boolean LookupPrivilegeValue(IntPtr lpSystemName, string lpname, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] ref LUID lpLuid);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern Boolean AdjustTokenPrivileges(IntPtr TokenHandle, Boolean DisableAllPrivileges, ref TOKEN_PRIVILEGES NewState, Int32 BufferLength, IntPtr PreviousState, IntPtr ReturnLength);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern Boolean SetTokenInformation(IntPtr TokenHandle, TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS TokenInformationClass, ref UInt32 TokenInformation, UInt32 TokenInformationLength);

        [DllImport("userenv.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern Boolean CreateEnvironmentBlock(ref IntPtr lpEnvironment, IntPtr hToken, Boolean bInherit);

        [DllImport("advapi32.DLL")]
        public static extern bool ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(IntPtr hToken); //handle to token for logged-on user

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern int DuplicateToken(IntPtr hToken, int impersonationLevel, ref IntPtr hNewToken);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "DuplicateTokenEx")]
        public static extern bool DuplicateTokenEx(IntPtr ExistingTokenHandle, uint dwDesiredAccess,
            ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes, int TokenType,
            int ImpersonationLevel, out/*ref*/ IntPtr DuplicateTokenHandle);

        ///
        /// A process should call the RevertToSelf function after finishing 
        /// any impersonation begun by using the DdeImpersonateClient, 
        /// ImpersonateDdeClientWindow, ImpersonateLoggedOnUser, ImpersonateNamedPipeClient, 
        /// ImpersonateSelf, ImpersonateAnonymousToken or SetThreadToken function.
        /// If RevertToSelf fails, your application continues to run in the context of the client,
        /// which is not appropriate. You should shut down the process if RevertToSelf fails.
        /// RevertToSelf Function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379317(VS.85).aspx
        ///
        /// A boolean value indicates the function succeeded or not.
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool RevertToSelf();



        [DllImport("shell32.dll")]
        public static extern bool SHGetSpecialFolderPath(IntPtr hwndOwner, [Out]StringBuilder lpszPath, int nFolder, bool fCreate);

        static string System32_SysWOW64_Folder()
        {
            StringBuilder path = new StringBuilder(260);
            SHGetSpecialFolderPath(IntPtr.Zero, path, 0x0029, false);
            return path.ToString();
        }

        //=================== Create directory =====================
        private static string CreateDirectoryAtSystemFolder()
        {
            string tmpDir = null;
            string sysFolderPath = System32_SysWOW64_Folder();
            //string sysFolderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData); //System32_SysWOW64_Folder();
            //string sysFolderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles); //ProgramFiles_Folder();
            tmpDir = sysFolderPath + "\\logdata"; //ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ImageSavedPath"].ToString();
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(@tmpDir))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(@tmpDir);
            }

            return tmpDir;
        }
    }
}
```

As I mentioned in my earlier edit, previously before adding `DuplicateTokenEx` & `SetTokenInformation`, the service was able to run the app but it could not log under System32 folder. To achieve that I updated to the above code and now the `SetTokenInformation()` method shows the privilege error.

***Edit:*** Finally the service could start my process on logged on user account and write all my log files at proper user appdata path. I have removed `SetTokenInformation`. Following code with `CreateEnvironmentBlock()` method helped the process get a separate user environment and retrieve the user appdata path.

```
int dwCreationFlags = DETACHED_PROCESS;
IntPtr pEnv = IntPtr.Zero;
if (CreateEnvironmentBlock(ref pEnv, hToken, true))
{
    dwCreationFlags |= CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT;
}
else
{
    pEnv = IntPtr.Zero;
}

bool ChildProcStarted = CreateProcessAsUser(
    hToken,                 // client's access token
    ChildProcName,          // file to execute
    null,                   // command line
    ref saProcess,          // pointer to process SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    ref saThread,           // pointer to thread SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    false,                  // handles are not inheritable
    dwCreationFlags,        // creation flags
    pEnv,                   // pointer to new environment block 
    null,                   // name of current directory 
    ref tStartUpInfo,       // pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
    out tProcessInfo        // receives information about new process
    );
```

Comment: What version of Windows?  XP, Vista, 7, 8, 8.1, or 10?  What error code is CreateProcessAsUser returning?

Comment: @HarryJohnston, both are Windows 7. Really sorry that I missed that info. I have edited the question. After CreateProcessAsUser I got the error "The requested operation requires elevation".

Comment: That means that the executable you're trying to launch will only run in an administrator account, either because the manifest specifies requireAdministrator, because it has no manifest and Windows heuristics have guessed that it is an installer, or because there is a compatibility setting in place to require it to run as admin.

Comment: Many thanks Harry. I solved this following your suggestion. I have some new problems though. Please see my edit. Also, if possible, please post your comment as an answer since it solved the problem.

Comment: OK, so the GUI application was intentionally configured to run as an administrator so that it could write those log files.  The proper solution is for the service, not the GUI application, to do the logging.  Similarly, the service should be doing all of the jobs that the user isn't allowed to interrupt, the GUI application should do nothing but present a user interface, so it doesn't matter if the user kills it.  There are other options though, depending on your particular needs and circumstances, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/a/21127414/886887

Comment: I have implemented this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2408050/3975223), which includes SetTokenInformation, but it returns the error "SetTokenInformation() failed (Last Error: 24, The program issued a command but the command length is incorrect)". Adding `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, 
    CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]` did not solve the problem.

Comment: I think because it passes `IntPtr.Size` rather than `Int32.Size` (or just `4`) as the buffer size.  But that code is bizarre - see my comments posted there.  Hopefully you're just trying to use it as an example of calling SetTokenInformation, and discarding the rest?

Comment: Thanks Harry. I have moved back to my previous code and updated with SetTokenInformation, but I get the privilege error now. Please see my edit.

Comment: Documentation says (edited slightly for clarity) "If TokenSessionId is set with SetTokenInformation, the application must have the Act As Part Of the Operating System privilege, and the privilege must be enabled."  But the code as currently posted is still using the user's token (as retrieved via WTSQueryUserToken) so it doesn't need to set the session ID.  Are you trying to run the new process as the user, or with administrative privilege?

Comment: Actually Harry, I am still trying to understand the theory of this code. **I want my process to run on logged on user account but with admin privilege (if possible) so that I can write my log files under system folder.** I am not sure about my code whether I am doing what I want.

Comment: Looking back, I think you are wrong in thinking that you want the process to run in the logged on user's account; that would allow the user to kill the process, and would only work if the user was an administrator.  I think you just want to run the process in the logged-on user's session, so that it can interact with the user.  If that's true, you don't need WTSQueryUserToken.  You should just duplicate your own token which you can get using GetCurrentProcess followed by OpenProcessToken and then set the session ID.  Note that this is risky; have you considered putting the log file elsewhere?

Comment: Separate version of my process needs to run for each user, hence I need to run the process on user account. So after your comment, I have removed `SetTokenInformation`. I am simply using `CreateProcessAsUser` to start my process on user account and trying to write all my log files under user appdata path, but don't know why every time my files are logged at _systemprofile_ (\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming), whereas if I run my process manually, I am getting my files successfully at _user appdata path_ (\Users\User1\AppData\Roaming). Another issue. Please help Harry.

Comment: Best guess?  The code is using the value of the `USERPROFILE` environment variable to determine where to put the log file.  By default, CreateProcessAsUser() copies your environment variables, but you can pass it a different set, either manually constructed or by using CreateEnvironmentBlock().

Comment: Thanks a lot Harry. I was already working around with CreateEnvironmentBlock() and I can now log the files at proper user appdata path. I have updated my question too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To summarize:

- The original problem was that the target executable was configured to require UAC elevation, but must be run in the user's context, even if the user is not an administrator.  This isn't directly related to the fact that it was being launched from a service, but that was a complicating factor because it meant that the attempt to launch the application failed rather than resulting in an elevation dialog.  The resolution was to change `requestedExecutionLevel` in the application's manifest from `requireAdministrator` to `asInvoker` which is the default value.
- When the application was reconfigured to not require UAC elevation, it failed to run properly because it was trying to write log files to a global folder.  The resolution was to write the log files to a suitable per-user location.
- The last issue was that the application was not finding the per-user location correctly when launched from the service.  This was because it was being given a copy of the service's environment block rather than one suitable to the user.  The resolution was to use [CreateEnvironmentBlock()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762270%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to generate a suitable environment block and pass it as CreateProcessAsUser's `lpEnvironment` argument.

Comment: This time I tried with a Windows XP machine and WTSEnumerateSessions is returning false with an error "The binding handle is invalid". I came across this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/841173). Is it the issue of windows update for that machine or there is some solution through my code? The first time on installing my msi setup, the service is able to start my process, but after a reboot the service fails to start the process with the above error message. I have checked that this XP machine has .Net framework 2, 3 and 3.5 installed.

Comment: That link isn't relevant to this scenario.  Most likely cause is that you aren't passing the right value for `WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE` (the first argument) possibly because of an incorrect P/Invoke declaration.  If you can't work it out, I recommend you post a new question.